# After filter a listview,how can I obtain the position of the first listview?

Tags: android, listview, filter, simpleadapter

After filter a listview,how can I obtain the position of the first listview?
I use simpleadapter to fill the listview. 
Each item in the datasource has its own id,and I use "case" to redirect them.
After I filter the listview ,I don't know how to associate the latter items with the first listview.The postion and id have changed.
Thank you.

I use the afterTextChanged of EditTextView to filter the listview and notify it.

```
            @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable paramEditable) {

            listItemsCopy.clear();
            int count=simpleAdapter.getCount();
            if ((count>0 )&&paramEditable.length()>0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < simpleAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    Map<String,Object> tempMap=(Map<String,Object>)simpleAdapter.getItem(i);
                    String itemName=tempMap.get("name").toString();
                    HashMap<String, Object> tempHashMap=new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    int copyCount=0;
                    if(itemName.toLowerCase().contains(paramEditable.toString().toLowerCase())){

                        tempHashMap=(HashMap<String, Object>)simpleAdapter.getItem(i);
                        listItemsCopy.add(tempHashMap);

                        copyCount++;
                    }
                }                       

        if(listItemsCopy!=null){
        Handler handler=new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                simpleAdaptercopy = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),
                        listItemsCopy, R.layout.right_menu_list_view, new String[] {
                                "name", "id", "image" }, new int[] {
                                R.id.rightMenuListViewTextView1,
                                R.id.rightMenuListViewTextView2,
                                R.id.rightMenuListViewImageView1 });

                simpleAdapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,
                            String textRepresentation) {
                        if ((view instanceof ImageView && data instanceof Bitmap)) {
                            ImageView iv = (ImageView) view;
                            iv.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) data);
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
                listView.setAdapter(simpleAdaptercopy);
                simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                                }
        }, 1000);
        }
            }
            else {
                listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
                simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
```

Then I want to  use the method  onItemClick of listview to redirect different Intent.As the datasource has changed,both position and id are different from which I want

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = null;
            switch (position) {}`
```

Comment: Post your source as what you have tried and part where you are stuck

Comment: @SankarV I have edited some code upper.

Comment: @CRUSADER I stuck in the method of onItemClick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I slove it with three arrays. Only test code:

```
String positionString[]=new String[22];
                int latterPosition[]=new int[22];
                for (int i = 0; i < latterPosition.length; i++) {
                    positionString[i]="";
                    latterPosition[i]=0;
                }
                int latterCount=0;
                for (int i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
                    if (positions[i]==10) {
                        positionString[latterCount]=i+"";
                        latterPosition[latterCount]=10;
                        latterCount++;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

this happens becouse Android gives you only IDs for the itmes you currently see + maybe two hidden on button and two hidden on top.

In [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced_interactive) tutorial you can see how to create a ListView with a model, this helps me, when i got this problem before. Add this to you code and change it (I think you don't need the checkboxes).

Comment: I slove it with three arrays.   Only test code:     `String positionString[]=new String[22];
    int latterPosition[]=new int[22];
    for (int i = 0; i < latterPosition.length; i++) {
     positionString[i]="";
     latterPosition[i]=0;
    }
    int latterCount=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
     if (positions[i]==10) {
      positionString[latterCount]=i+"";
      latterPosition[latterCount]=10;
      latterCount++;
     }
    }`