# Searchbar Changing Positions due to filtering

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, webview

I have been working on a project, in which i have a main activity in which i have listview and one search bar(edit text bar) and the onitemclicklistener of my listview passes the row position to a activity having webview and the webview opens html pages to their respective positions. i also have my listview items stored in arrays.xml

my problem starts here- my Listview Works file and opens respective activity on row click (when i dont use search bar and just scroll and click on row.)

but when i use the searchbar to search for an item (html page) for instance let it be "c" and i click on it , the listview DoesNot open the correct html page!. hope this is clear. i have around thousands of html files so stroring all the positions in the java file is not possible because of limited heap size. i found one solution here    [After filter a listview,how can I obtain the position of the first listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393538/after-filter-a-listview-how-can-i-obtain-the-position-of-the-first-listview)
but i have no idea how do i implement this in my code.

```
    here is my main activity

package com.Sample.htmlOpener;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ListView list1;
private String array[] ;
EditText inputSearch; 
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch); 
list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray);
adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
list1.setAdapter(adapter);
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // When user changed the Text
    MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
 }
 });

list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,WebViewActivity.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("key",position);
    startActivity(myIntent);
 }
 });   
}
```

}

and here is my webview activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
WebView web;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    int pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("key",0);
    if(pos==0)
    {
        web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file.html");
    }
    else
    {
        web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file" + pos + ".html");
    }
  // similarly for 4 and 5 and so on.
 }

 public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
 {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
            String description, String failingUrl) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // List view
    private ListView lv;

    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;


    String[] productsList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        productsList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list);


        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        // Adding items to listview
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list));
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                            int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
            }
        });

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String productName = adapter.getItem(position);

                for ( int i=0;i<productsList.length;i++){

                    String product = productsList[i];

                    if ( product.equals(productName)){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Original Position of Item in  listview "+i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    }                   
               }
            }

        });
    }

}
```

See : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

Comment: i told you that i have thousands of html files , please read the description thoroughly

Comment: my listview items are in listarrays.xml and i dont to write them again and again please modify your code

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="myArray">

Comment: Now check my updated answer it use the array from xml

Comment: this is not working , please please please check the code in question, i want to pass the item position to another activity please have a look at both the codes ,

Comment: please check my code again and user this code `adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray));` for setting adapter to listview

Comment: I place the toast to show the original position of item in list view

Comment: You just create new project using my code and check, it working fine at my side.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you have thousands of items so checking for a match is not a good option. What you can do is , you can create a custom list adapter and set a tag for each item. And in onclick on listview you can get that tag and use it.